# Centers and Quotients of Groups

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-homomorphism, quotient-group

This question occured to me when I was working with upper central series:

Let $K\le N$ be normal subgroups of $G$. Then there is some normal subgroup $M$ of $G$ satisfying $M/N = Z(G/N)$. I claim that

$$Z\left( \frac{G/K}{N/K} \right) = \frac{M/K}{N/K}$$

I wrote down all the details of my claim using cosets. But that is too tedious.

I am looking for alternative ways of proving this claim. Is there any result I can use to make it follow easily?

Comment: $\frac{G/K}{N/K}\cong G/N$, $\frac{M/K}{N/K}\cong M/N=Z(G/N)$.

Comment: @markvs I planned on using the third isomorphism theorem. Since $\frac{G/K}{N/K}$ is isomorphic to $G/N$, I can conclude that $Z \left( \frac{G/K}{N/K} \right)$ is isomorphic to $Z(G/N)$ and consequently $Z \left( \frac{G/K}{N/K} \right)$ is isomorphic to $\frac{M/K}{N/K}$. How can I ensure that equality holds?

Comment: It's just a matter of observing that the isomorphism $\frac{G/K}{N/K} \to G/N$ maps $\frac{M/K}{N/K}$ to M/N$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thank you! Since isomorphisms map center of groups to center, we are done!