# Proof Verification: $G/Z(G)$ is nilpotent implies $G$ is nilpotent

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, nilpotent-groups

I wrote a proof down for the fact that if $G/Z (G)$ is nilpotent then $G$ is nilpotent and I wonder if this is correct. I would appreciate it if someone verifies this and/or suggests some alternative ways of doing this.

---

I intend to prove this using the upper central series. Let us denote $G/Z(G)$ as $\overline{G}$. Let
$$\{ Z(G) \}=Z_{0} (\overline{G}) \triangleleft Z_{1} (\overline{G})\triangleleft \ldots\triangleleft Z_{n} (\overline{G}) \triangleleft \ldots$$
be the upper central series for $\overline{G}$. Since each $Z_i(\overline{G})$ is a subgroup of $\overline G$, we can find subgroups $H_i$ of $G$ such that $Z_i (\overline G) =\frac{H_i}{Z(G)}$ by the [Lattice Isomorphism Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_theorem_(group_theory)) for Groups. Again by the Lattice Isomorphism Theorem, we obtain
$$Z(G) = H_0 \triangleleft H_1 \triangleleft\ldots\triangleleft H_n \triangleleft \ldots$$
Let
$$\{ e \}=Z_{0} (G) \triangleleft Z_{1} (G)\triangleleft \ldots\triangleleft Z_{n} (G) \triangleleft \ldots$$

be the upper central series for $G$.

I claim that $H_i = Z_{i+1} (G)$ for each $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. I prove it using induction. The case where $i=0$ is immediate. Assume that $H_{i-1} = Z_{i} (G)$. Then we have
\begin{align*} \frac{Z_{i}(\overline{G})}{Z_{i-1}(\overline{G})} &= Z \left( \frac{\overline{G}}{Z_{i-1} (\overline{G})} \right) &\text{(by definition)}\\\frac{H_{i} / Z(G)}{H_{i-1} /Z(G)} &= Z \left( \frac{G/Z(G)}{H_{i-1}/Z (G)} \right) & \text{} \\ \frac{H_{i} / Z(G)}{Z_i (G) /Z(G)} &= Z \left( \frac{G/Z(G)}{Z_i(G)/Z (G)} \right) & \text{(by induction hypothesis)}\end{align*}

Since $Z_{i+1}(G)/Z_i (G) = Z(G/Z_i(G))$, we have from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4353106/centers-and-quotients-of-groups) that
$$Z \left( \frac{G/Z(G)}{Z_i(G)/Z (G)} \right) = \frac{Z_{i+1}(G) /Z(G)}{Z_i (G) /Z(G)}$$

From the previous two equations, we have
$$\frac{Z_{i+1}(G) /Z(G)}{Z_i (G) /Z(G)} = \frac{H_{i} / Z(G)}{Z_i (G) /Z(G)}$$

Applying the Lattice Isomorphism Theorem twice, we have that $Z_{i+1} (G) = H_i$. This completes the proof of my claim.

Since $\overline G$ is nilpotent, we have that $H_c = G$ for some $c \in \mathbb N$. Consequently from my claim, $Z_{c-1} (G) = G$ which shows that $G$ is nilpotent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks fine, but a bit complicated. I am using $\gamma$'s and $\zeta$'s to denote the lower and upper central series respectively. Why don't you use the fact that $$\gamma_i(G/\zeta(G))=\gamma_i(G)\zeta(G)/\zeta(G).$$ This is easy to prove with induction on $i$. Once you have this, assume that $G/\zeta(G)$ is nilpotent of class $c$, so $\gamma_{c+1}(G/\zeta(G))=\overline{1}$. The above formula then yields $\gamma_{c+1}(G) \subseteq \zeta(G)$, implying $\gamma_{c+2}(G)=[G,\gamma_{c+1}(G)]=1$, so $G$ is nilpotent.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I wouldn't have thought of making such a claim. Could you explain intuitively how you came up with $\gamma_i(G/\zeta(G))=\gamma_i(G)\zeta(G)/\zeta(G)$?

Comment: Well, the definition of the a nilpotent group in terms of lower and upper central series stopping at a finite number of steps, gives you that $\gamma_i(G)=1$ for certain $i \geq 1$ iff $G$ is nilpotent. So if $G/\zeta(G)$ is nilpotent, you might wonder what $\gamma_i(G/\zeta(G))$ is and trying to prove that it is trivial after a finite number of steps $i$. Now if $i=2$, then you need to figure out what the commutator subgroup of $G/\zeta(G)$ is. That is where it starts - commutators behave very neatly under taking quotients, leading to $(G/\zeta(G))'=G'\zeta(G)/\zeta(G)$.

Comment: Dually, going along the upper central series, you might try to figure out what $\zeta_i(G/\zeta(G))$ is. I will give you the answer: it is $\zeta_{i+1}(G)/\zeta(G)$. So also this approach would work. Can you see it?

Comment: My proof showed that $\zeta_i(G/\zeta(G)) = \zeta_{i+1}(G)/\zeta(G)$, didn't it? So the claim you made is basically a dual version of this?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: One more question, can I omit $\zeta(G)$ and write $\gamma_i(G/\zeta(G))=\gamma_i(G)/\zeta(G)$? I wrote a proof for this and everything seems okay.

Comment: No, since $\zeta(G)$, in general, is not contained in $\gamma_i(G)$. You need the full image of $\gamma_i(G)$ in $G/\zeta(G)$.

Comment: Can you take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4355550/showing-gizg-zg-g-zgi ?